# Convert all text to to Title Case in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to convert all text in a range of cells to *Title Case* automatically.

How can I do that?

Comment: Is there a difference in title-case and proper-case? There is the formula =PROPER("string")

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) for this purpose. The function `titleCaseRange` title-cases the content of the currently selected range (which may be a single cell or a rectangular block). The function `titleCase` is used by it to handle an individual string.

```
function titleCaseRange() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  if (values.map) {
    range.setValues(values.map(function(row) {
      return row.map(titleCase);
    }));
  }    
  else {
    range.setValue(titleCase(values));
  }
}

function titleCase(str) {
  return str.toString().split(/\b/).map(function(word) {
    return word ? word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase() : '';
  }).join('');
}
```

The logic can be adapted to other situations, e.g., you may want to have a custom function like `=title(A3:B8)` that converts a range to title case (but no longer in the same place as the data originally was). This would use the same `titleCase` above, but the rest would be different:

```
function title(values) {
  if (values.map) {
    return values.map(function(row) {
      return row.map(titleCase);
    });
  }    
  else {
    return titleCase(values);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What about, if i want to select automatically 3 cells every 7 rows ?

Comment: Then you should probably replace the `values.map` things by loops like `for (var i = 0; i <values.length, i++) { for (var j = 0; j < values[0].length; j++ ) { // some logic to decide if you want title case or not } }`